# Xilium CefGlue in Vline can only receive calls

Tags: chromium-embedded, vline, cefglue

I have set up a vLine agent withing Xilium CefGlue and mostly it works. It can send text messages, receive voice and video calls that function as expected but when a voice or video call is made out of CefGlue to a Chrome browser or CefGlue the call appears to connect but no video or audio makes it from one client to the other. Local vidoe is displayed and it appears local audio is being captured but the other client can see nor hear anything.

[1202/163721:ERROR:webrtc_audio_renderer.cc(231)] NOT IMPLEMENTED shows up in CefGlue.log

Any ideas what can be done to make this work?

Comment: Is it possible for you to run the Web Client (https://your-service-name.vline.com) in CefGlue and test making and receiving calls with that? Similarly, can you run your custom code in two normal Chrome browsers and verify that calls work in both directions?

Comment: my-service.vline.com does not work because the login pop-up is not suported. I can make calls in both directions from Chrome browsers.

Comment: Does https://gittogether.com work in CefGlue? (That is essentially the Web Client with a GitHub login). Is it possible to turn on verbose Chromium logging in CefGlue? For example, with Chrome we use the following flags to get verbose logging: `--enable-logging --v=4`

Answer (score 0):

Run application (or add it programmatically) with --enable-media-stream switch.
http://apprtc.appspot.com/ should work.

If problems still persists, but works in chrome - then you probably should report issue into CEF issue tracker, or there is problem with vLine (what is it?).

Comment: i have used --enable-media-stream. It does look like CEF could use an update but [link](https://opentokrtc.com/) does get video transfer independent of weather a Cef or chrome browser is the first to enter the room though if the chrome client is the first, the same not implemented error does appear. This implies that there is a way to get cef to work, though the presence of an error may mean that there really shouldn't be.

Comment: Also i got another error:[1202/162509:ERROR:webrtc_local_audio_renderer.cc(85)] NOT IMPLEMENTEDWebRtcLocalAudioRenderer::SetCaptureFormat(), that might be more usefull cause it seems to point more directly to what went wrong

Comment: I'm still not understand the problem.
Reproduce it with native cefclient and report bug to CEF. CefGlue just a .net bindings to CEF. Better is try made it with latest stable branch (1650) and current development branch.